# How to pick same values in a list if the list contain floating numbers

Tags: python, list, numpy, dictionary

In the following code I want to check how many unique values are in the list and this can be done in for loop. After knowing the number of unique values I want to see how many times a single unique values appear in a and then I want to count their number. Can someone please guide me how to do that. List contains floating points. What if I convert it in numpy array and then find same values.

```
`a= [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3.0, 3.0]
list = []
for i in a:
    if i not in list:
        list.append(i)

print(list)
for j in range(len(list))
    g= np.argwhere(a==list[j])
    print(g)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use np.unique to get it done

```
np.unique(np.array(a),return_counts=True)
```

You can also do it using counters from collections

```
from collections import Counter
Var=dict(Counter(a))
print(Var)
```

The primitive way is to use loops

```
[[x,a.count(x)] for x in set(a)]
```

If you are not familiar with list comprehensions, this is its explaination

```
ls=[]
for x in set(a):
    ls.append([x,a.count(x)])
print(ls)
```

If you want it using if else,

```
counter = dict()
for k in a:
    if not k in counter:
        counter[k] = 1
    else:
        counter[k] += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: Why do you need loops, the best part about numpy and pandas is everything can be vectorised, in the end, a code should be memory efficient right?

Comment: You can make use of counters or dictionary

Comment: yes I'm trying to learn programming. Just want to learn an alternate way. I tried to use loop several times but could not figure it out

Comment: Please verify the answer as you got what you were looking for. Happy coding! :D

Comment: Can you please modify loop by using if else statement. Means comapre previous element with the next element and then decide counting

Comment: verify the answer as you got your solution @user10163680